# Vulnerabilities of not using PHP OOP

Tags: php, security, oop

I love doing programming in PHP. But I dont prefer doing it the OOP way for **small tasks**. I know that OOPs have many advantages like Polymorphism, inheritance, abstraction, etc, but I prefer the hard-coded technique to solve simple problems. Are **there any kind of** vulnerabilities associated with this approach? ***Can anyone please show me some code examples to make a non-OOP program safe?***

Comment: Object oriented programming is just a [paradigm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_paradigm) - e.g. a way of programming. Thus there should not be any obvious vulnerabilities by language design. Although there might be vulnerabilities if you use outdated methods instead of a newer OOP version.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A programming paradigm doesn't make a piece of software safer. Good practices, technology knowledge, a thorough understanding of platform-specific and environment-specific security concepts, and good logging are the best way of achieving a rock-solid system in terms of security.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it's quite like that. As long as you write good code and have security in mind, no matter which approach you use your code should stand up. As far as I know shoddy OOP code is just as bad as shoddy procedural.

Answer (score 2):

There are no vulnerabilities associated with using a procedural approach instead of an OOP approach. The same vulnerabilities are possible either way.

If you are writing functionality yourself instead of using a trusted class, then perhaps you have to be more careful. One can not give an example of code that will make code safer, you need to understand the consequences of what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

Conceptually, there's nothing inherently more *secure* about writing OOP code vs prodedural code. They're just different coding styles. You can write good or bad code in either of them.

There are features in PHP which use OOP which do provide better functionality than their old-style counterparts, but even then most of that functionality is also available in procedural style functions as well as classes.

I would recommend dipping your toes into OOP development -- it can be rewarding once you've got the knack of it, and PHP makes it easy to ease yourself into it without having to throw away your old procedural code and coding habits all at once. It is a good thing to learn, and it will improve your code, but it isn't a security issue.